# How to apply Google Sheets 'HTTPResponse' to entire column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas, http-response-codes

I have a Google sheet with Column A and Column B. Under column A I list URLs and under column B I want to run this formula `=HTTPResponse ()`. Since I have many URLs that I will insert via Google Forms I want the sheet automatically to apply the same formula to all URLs without me typing `=HTTPResponse (B2)`, `=HTTPResponse (B3)`,..  so one for entire Column B cells.

[image]

I typed `=HTTPResponse (A2)` in B2 cell and `=ARRAYFORMULA(B2:B)` in B1 cell and I receive this error:

```
Error on Column B1:
#REF!
Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B2
```

and the formula code I added:

```
function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
var response_code ;
try {
response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
}
catch( error ) {
response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (ddd)./ )[1] ;
}
finally {
return response_code ;
}
}
```

Why do I keep getting this error and why is `=HTTPResponse` not applied for the entire column of data (old, and new inserted data)?

Comment: you posted similar question already. using a custom function will not work for your purpose because google will forever cache the response it gets for each unique url. so it will not fail ever after for the same url even if server is down or response changed.

Comment: Thanks for rrply . So what is the solution?  I know people has used spreadsheet for finding dead links!

Comment: solution is on your other (basically duplicate) that you absndoned

Answer (score 0):

You should probably clear the cell B2 as this is preventing the formula result from expanding.

Comment: Thanks for reply. if i do that then how to apply httpresponse for entire column A and write the status on Column B? i tried =HTTPResponse(A2:A) on Cell B1 but all cells empty no status.i have hard time fixing this . I khow i can copy the formula for entire column by mouse but how to do it automatically so when i insert new urls it automatically write status next to it !